# Accept alert is not working in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I need to accept a browser alert if any change is made. Here is my code. Strangely ,  i do not see any changes even after i accept the alert.

Ex : Deleting an item from the list , the browser throws an alert. I accepted the alert. But i could still see the item in the list. –

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent(), 1000);
browser.switchTo().alert().then(function(alert) {
  alert.accept();
});
```

protractor version : 5.3.0
Chrome driver: 2.36
OS : MACOS

Comment: Can you elaborate? "Is not working" is not very clear.  Does it throw an error?  What if you extend the `alertIsPresent` timeout or add a sleep etc?

Comment: Nope it it not throwning any error. Same time , after accepting the alert i do not see any changes. Ex : Deleting an item from the list , the browser throws an alert. I accepted the alert. But i could still see the item in the list.

Comment: Could some one please help. I am still stuck with it !!